# How to find list of files which were modified on a particular date in the entire HP Unix server

Tags: unix

I need list of files which were modified on a particular date in HP Unix server.

I need all the files not from a single directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
dateToFind=2011-05-18
find . -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %p\n" | egrep "^$dateToFind " | sed "s/^$dateToFind //g"
```

The use of find with the -mtime option may be faster, but has some difficulties. First, I don't see an option for an absolute date, so you would have to calculate start and end time offsets. Second, your time offsets will quickly become invalid, so you probably need the -daystart option. Even then, there could be issues if you are trying to run this near midnight.

Also, files that were modified on that date and then modified later will not be listed. I don't know of a way to determine these subsequently modified files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `find` file search tool, more specificaly its `-mtime` and `-newer` options.

Answer (score 0):

```
: ${2?usage: $0 [[CC]YY]MMDD pathname}
touch -t${1}0000.00 /tmp/$$-zerosec
touch -t${1}2359.59 /tmp/$$-lastsec
find $2 -newer /tmp/$$-zerosec ! -newer /tmp/$$-lastsec
rm /tmp/$$-????sec
```

We call this script with arguments date (as with `touch`) and pathname (`/` for the whole directory tree). Note that this will not find files modified in the first second of the day, and additionally find the file `/tmp/$$-lastsec` if `/tmp` is searched.